# spring security oauth2 post restriction

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently trying to implement a spring application with spring security oauth2 to protect my resource as well as receving data from external device (eg. IOS or Android app)
With following spring config settings, I can achieve the goal of protecting resource, so basically anyone wish to view the json data , they have to go through

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<!-- Protected resources -->
<http pattern="/searchResultAPI/**" 
      create-session="never"
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/searchResultAPI/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/receiveUserDataAPI/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
                   before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler
            ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="dstest"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client"/>
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Authentication in config file -->
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>

<!-- Token Store  -->
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
    <!-- VIV -->
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
</bean>

<!-- Token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code/>
    <oauth:implicit/>
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:password/>
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                       resource-id="dstest"
                       token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

<!-- Client Definition -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

    <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client"
                  authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
                  authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
                  redirect-uri="/web"
                  scope="read,write,trust"
                  access-token-validity="30"
                  refresh-token-validity="600"/>

</oauth:client-details-service>


<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
</sec:global-method-security>
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>

</beans>
```

1.to get refresh token

```
http://www.sample.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=admin&password=password
```

2. Refresh token exchange access token

   http://www.sample.com/oauth/token?client_id=my-trusted-client&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=5fbdc1fe-6d26-458a-818f-4e49c41a47ff
3. Final step use access token to access json data

   http://www.sample.com/searchResultAPI/results?search_item_id=0098&access_token=3658213e-5bb0-4c4b-89ca-f0f82513fc22

I have no problem with above process to retrieve data.

However,  When I am trying to post some data to this url (assume servlet requestmapping is for this url, and all gson orm and model done etc...),  the spring security does not stopping the post to `http://www.sample.com/receiveUserDataAPI/receiver`  , even without initially calling `oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=admin&password=password`  to gain access token.

```
{
"customer":
    {
        "address": "somewhere",
        "city": "London",
    }

}
```

It just directly putting the data into the data base through this servlet.
Ideally, my plan was just like retreive data process, grant user access token 1st, then use token to post data, spring security check token valid and then receive data. I guess it should post json data to url something like `http://www.sample.com/receiveUserDataAPI/receiver?&access_token=3658213e-5bb0-4c4b-89ca-f0f82513fc22`  ?
Can anyone point me out where did I set wrong or I missed to set any properties?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your client received access token put it into request header: {'Authorization': 'Bearer {access_token}'} for any protected resource on your server. Spring automatically check this token and owner permissions.

Comment: errr, didnt really get that...  so basically, my server not wish to receive any data from stranger, when someone doing the post,  currently, with above oauth2 config xml  it does not stopping people posting stuff. cheers